# Data imputation based on the mean of the numeric variable and the frequency count of a categorical variable

Tags: r, mean, imputation, proportions

I have a data frame having many rows that contain random missing variable of Gender and Age. A similar count of Gender and Age together with the missing values is represented below using the below DF.
From the DF, the % population of females is 60%, & the average mean of males and females is 33 and 39 respectively.

```
Gender <- c("Male", " ", " ", "Female", "Female", " ",  " ", "Male", " ", "Female")
Age <- c(' ', 33, 33, 39, 39, 33,33, 33, 32, 39)
Data2 <- data.frame(Gender, Age)
Data2$Age <- as.numeric(Data2$Age)
Data2$Gender <- as.character(Data2$Gender)
```

I'd like to impute the missing values according to the count proportion of males and females and the mean values of males and females.

How do I do that in R?

Comment: You should not impute missing values with the mean. Use multiple imputation instead, e.g. by using the [mice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) package. Also, your question only shows data, but not a coding problem that we could help you with.

Comment: https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/mi.html

Comment: I agree with @jay.sf: imputing on the mean narrows the apparent variance of your results, which will affect tests and interpretation. It's generally better to choose one of several other techniques, most generally stratified. I think the mention of MI (wrt MCAR, MAR, or MNAR from user330's link) is applicable, can definitely inform the stratification process. From there, hot-decking (sampled imputation) may be sufficient for you.

Comment: But to be more specific, I think imputing `Gender` here is just wrong. Similar to other concepts in the MI link above, un-reported gender is likely due to _something_ that could be relevant, and imputing it and then using `Gender` as a categorical strata in your analysis is going to be suspect.